# Get central content from a Web Page

Tags: parsing, nlp, semantic-markup

What are the possible ways to get the central content of a web page?

By central content I mean the content which is most important in the page.

Eg: in the web page http://techcrunch.com/2011/05/27/iphone-app-notifies-you-when-your-laundrys-done/

the central content would be:

```
<p><img src="http://tctechcrunch.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/screen-shot-2011-05-27-at-10-11-36-pm.png" alt=""><br>
The folks that brought you <a href="http://itsthisforthat.com/">It’sthisforthat</a> have created another way to make your life just a little bit easier and funnier. Meet&nbsp;<a href="http://www.dryerbro.com">DryerBro</a>, an app that uses an accelerometer to let you know when your laundry’s done.</p>
<p>With DryerBro you put your iPhone or iTouch on your laundry machine and it texts you and the remaining members of your laundry party when your laundry’s done. I’m thinking this is going to be HUGE. I mean Facebook took off at colleges right?</p>
<p>Once set up, DryerBro uses an accelerometer and Twilio to send a SMS, email or call to multiple phones when your unmentionables are ready to be picked up.</p>
<p>Says creator Eric Kerr, “We live in a house with 11 dudes, and we’re seriously unorganized about laundry. We all want to use the machine on the weekends, but no one ever knows when the last load was done. It bothered me as hackers that we had the tools (accelerometer, Twilio) to solve the problem, but didn’t do anything about it.”</p>
<p>So they built DryerBro. “We originally looked to see if an app already used the accelerometer to detect when your laundry is done but we couldn’t find anything – it’s a blue ocean strategy,” he says.</p>
<p>Kerr and company are completely ridiculous, but their thing apparently works. When asked about future plans for DryerBro he told TechCrunch:</p>
<p>“Ultimately we want to build out a hyper-local group buying ad platform for laundry detergents. Rough back of the napkin calculations indicate that we’d need roughly $41 million in financing, so we’re asking friends and family to help pony up the dough. We also want to build out the map of every active dryer in the world to hang on the wall of our office.”</p>
<p>Both the DryerBro<a href="http://dryerbro.com/"> FAQ</a> and Promo video are awesome. You can download the iPhone <a href="http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dryer-bro/id425920156?mt=8">app here.</a>&nbsp;Promo video below.</p>
<div style="text-align:center;">
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="620" height="300" data="http://www.vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=20732587&amp;server=www.vimeo.com&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=01AAEA">
<param name="quality" value="best">
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
<param name="scale" value="showAll">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=20732587&amp;server=www.vimeo.com&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=01AAEA">
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
</object>
</div>
```

Any pointers in this regard would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: You have to define how the important content is recognized, what makes the content important

Comment: That is the point of the question, are there any NLP methods to get the most important part of a content. One way could be to compare it with similar web-pages and remove the common parts like header, menu, sidebars etc, but its not NLP.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extensive discussion about this topic at [metaoptimize](http://metaoptimize.com/qa/questions/3440/text-extraction-from-html-pages).

One of the posts there directs to a [list of resources](http://tomazkovacic.com/blog/56/list-of-resources-article-text-extraction-from-html-documents/) and [an overview of approaches](http://tomazkovacic.com/blog/14/extracting-article-text-from-html-documents/), both on Tomaz Kovacic's blog, and both very good.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [automatic summarisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_summarization) it is extract most central sentenences from text by described algorithms. For examples how it works you can check [my implementation](http://g-calendar.appspot.com/analyze) of several algorithms